# What is the value of tan θ in this problem?

Tags: trigonometry

If $\vec{A} = 4\vec{i}+3\vec{j}$, $\vec{B} = 5\vec{i}-12\vec{j}$ and $\theta$ is the measure of the angle between the two vectors $\vec{A}$ and $\vec{B}$, then what is the value of $\tan \theta$?

Comment: Try using the dot product

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments use the dot product, which can be obtained via 2 ways, one using coordinates and the other using the angle between the vectors. So we have:

$$4 \times 5 + 3 \times (-12) = \vec{A} \cdot \vec{B} = \sqrt{4^2 + 3^2} \sqrt{5^2 + (-12)^2} \cos \theta$$
$$-16 = 65 \cos \theta \implies \cos \theta = \frac{-16}{65}$$

From here you can use some of the well-known trigonometric identities to find the value of $\tan \theta$.